# akka serializer of scalaz.NonEmptyList (java.io.NotSerializableException)

Tags: scala, serialization, akka, scalaz

Does any have an implementation of a serializer to resolve this problem, or know of any pleasing work arounds?

I found this
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaz/Dkvi3d-D7S4
Which suggests a future marking of NonEmptyList to serializable which has yet to be or cannot be done.

Comment: Couldn't you just convert back to a scala.collection.List right before serialization?

Comment: On that kind of front, the best solution I've had is just to drop the non empty list entirely and use a list.  The nonempty aspect wasnt really adding much

Comment: Have you tried jackson with the objectmapper with installed the Scala module?

Comment: hmmm, json serializing it could be an option in my case

Comment: OK I was able to serialize with Json, cheers!